# xCode 4.6.3 how to fix autolayout crash in Mac OSX 10.8.4 ( Failed to run one shot request for IBNSLayoutConstraint)?

Tags: crash, osx-mountain-lion, autolayout, xcode4.6.3

I've recently upgraded my OSX from snow leopard to mountain lion and am running into an issue where my xCode shuts down 100% of the time within 5 seconds of opening any project. Here's the error message given. I've tried googling the error, but cannot find any info on the subject.

The error appears on opening any project, not just autolayout ones. The message "Waiting for other symbol copying" appears in the status bar on top, then xCode crashes with the exception listed below.

I remember that xCode asked me to install some additional component after OSX upgrade, but it crashed in the process of doing so and did not ask me again.

I tried re-installing xCode through the app store, but this did not fix the issue.

**How can I fix/repair my xCode installation to fix the error?**

```
Process:         Xcode [2957]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6.3 (2068)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2068000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 15588541
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [130]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-07-11 08:14:22.608 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          2375 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  18 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      F0403235-5ECB-ADEA-6618-E5526B9FE281

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-2083/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:651
Details:  Failed to run one shot request for IBNSLayoutConstraint, IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUIView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: [[self constant] symbolicValue] || (floor(constantValue) == constantValue)
Reason:     Constraint constants should be integral (constant attempted to be set to -10.500000). Foundation will always integralize the output anyways, so if constants are not integralized, this will almost always lead to arbitration failures. Constraint is <IBNSLayoutConstraint: 0x8191060> UILabel[0x817b130].Center X = UITableViewCell[0x8183690].Center X - 10.500000 containingView={<(null):0x0>} scoreVector=<0.000000, 3, 1, 1000.000000, 0>, roundingAdjustment=0
File:       /SourceCache/IBAutolayoutFoundationIOS/IBAutolayoutFoundation-2065/Framework/Classes/Model/Constraints/IBNSLayoutConstraint.m:460
Method:     -[IBNSLayoutConstraint assertConstraintValidity]
Exception backtrace: 
  0. CoreFoundation           0x022ad012 __exceptionPreprocess
  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x0170ce7e objc_exception_throw
  2. CoreFoundation           0x02335fb1 -[NSException raise]
  3. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0008be44 -[IBNSLayoutConstraint assertConstraintValidity]
  4. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0007b97f -[IBLayoutConstraint initWithFirstItem:firstAttribute:relation:secondItem:secondAttribute:constant:]
  5. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000899d2 -[IBNSLayoutConstraint initWithFirstItem:firstAttribute:relation:secondItem:secondAttribute:constant:]
  6. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0007c1ca -[IBLayoutConstraint copyWithZone:]
  7. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x00089dfe -[IBNSLayoutConstraint copyWithZone:]
  8. libobjc.A.dylib          0x01720ae9 -[NSObject copy]
  9. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0007e0e5 -[IBLayoutConstraint constraintByReplacingView:withView:andReplacingView:withView:]
 10. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ac46b -[IBAutolayoutEngine representedConstraintBySubstitutingRealViewsForRepresentedViewsOfConstraint:]
 11. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ac5f6 -[IBAutolayoutEngine addRepresentedConstraintForRealConstraint:]
 12. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ae959 -[IBAutolayoutEngine constraintsMakingSystemOverConstrainedByAddingConstraint:toView:]
 13. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000b803a +[IBAutolayoutArbiter attemptToAddConstraint:byModifyingLayoutEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraintBreakageStrategy:mutableConstraintsToAdd:mutableConstraintsToRemove:]
 14. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ace27 -[IBAutolayoutEngine performEngineBootstrappingConstraintAdditionOperationForAddingConstraint:]
 15. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ad46e __90-[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]_block_invoke404
 16. CoreFoundation           0x0229acdf __NSDictionaryEnumerate
 17. CoreFoundation           0x0229a87d -[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
 18. CoreFoundation           0x0229a7c5 -[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]
 19. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000ad150 -[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]
 20. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000a7db9 -[IBAutolayoutEngine initWithArbitrationUnit:options:]
 21. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000c1454 -[IBAutolayoutFrameDecisionDriver initWithArbitrationUnit:options:]
 22. ???                      0x0000c5a9 [IBCocoaTouchTool _startAutolayoutFrameDecisionSessionWithRequest:document:]
 23. ???                      0x0000d49c [IBCocoaTouchTool runOneShotIncrementalFrameDecisionRequest:withFrameDecisionSessionRequest:document:]
 24. ???                      0x00034fa5 [IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:result:]
 25. ???                      0x00034cea [IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:result:]
 26. ???                      0x000349d5 [IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:]
 27. libdispatch.dylib        0x04c4c731 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
 28. libdispatch.dylib        0x04c5b014 _dispatch_client_callout
 29. libdispatch.dylib        0x04c4b7d5 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
 30. CoreFoundation           0x02253af5 __CFRunLoopRun
 31. CoreFoundation           0x02252f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 32. CoreFoundation           0x02252e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode
 33. Foundation               0x013113ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
 34. ???                      0x0000d981 [IBCocoaTouchTool startServingReceiveChannel:]
 35. ???                      0x0000db1a [IBCocoaTouchTool startServingWithSocket:]
 36. ???                      0x0000ec89 [IBCocoaTouchTool .cxx_destruct]
 37. ???                      0x00002c15 ???
 38. ???                      0x00000003 ???
Exception info:{
}
```

Comment: I typed in a whole bunch of statements into terminal, that I found by "reset xcode" or "uninstall xcode". Not sure if they worked. After that, alt+shift clicking the xcode app in applications started xcode with a blank welcome screen (no project). Opening a project from there appears to have worked - the exception did not manifest itself again